How to dynamically update table row based on user input
I'm trying to create a dynamic HTML table that updates its rows based on user input. The table should display a list of items with their corresponding prices.
Problem:
When the user clicks the "Add Item" button, the new row is added, but I want to:

Validate user input (e.g., check if item name is not empty and price is a positive number).
Update the table rows dynamically when the user changes the input fields.
Remove duplicate item names.


Using change event on input fields, doesn't update the table rows.
Using blur event on input fields, but it doesn't validate input

Any guidance or code snippets would be greatly appreciated!


$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#add-item').click(function() {
    // Get user input
    var itemName = $('#item-name').val();
    var itemPrice = $('#item-price').val();

    // Create new table row
    var newRow = $('<tr>');
    newRow.append($('<td>').text(itemName));
    newRow.append($('<td>').text(itemPrice));

    // Add row to table body
    $('#item-table tbody').append(newRow);
  });
});
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table id="item-table">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Item</th>
      <th>Price</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <!-- rows will be generated dynamically -->
  </tbody>
</table>

<input type="text" id="item-name" placeholder="Enter item name">
<input type="number" id="item-price" placeholder="Enter item price">
<button id="add-item">Add Item</button>




It is not clear what you want. Do you want to remove the add item button and have the rows appear when the user starts typing? When would you know when they are done? What if they start typing, change their mind and delete what they type, how to know that the row is not complete? How do we know what row we are on when they want to change the row?

Below is complete solution of your problem


$(document).ready(function () {
  $("#add-item").click(function() {
    var itemName = $("#item-name").val().trim();
    var itemPrice = $("#item-price").val();

    if (!validateInputs(itemName, itemPrice)) {
      return;
    }

    if (isDuplicate(itemName)) {
      alert("Item already exists!");
      return;
    }
    var newRow = $("<tr>");
    newRow.append($("<td>").text(itemName));
    newRow.append($("<td>").text(itemPrice));

    $("#item-table tbody").append(newRow);
    $("#item-name").val("");
    $("#item-price").val("");
  });
  function validateInputs(itemName, itemPrice) {
    var isValid = true;
    $(".error").removeClass("error");
    if (!itemName) {
      $("#item-name").addClass("error");
      isValid = false;
    }

    if (!itemPrice || itemPrice <= 0) {
      $("#item-price").addClass("error");
      isValid = false;
    }

    return isValid;
  }
  function isDuplicate(itemName) {
    let exists = false;
    $("#item-table tbody tr").each(function () {
      if ($(this).find("td").first().text() === itemName) {
        exists = true;
      }
    });
    return exists;
  }
  $("#item-name, #item-price").on("input", function () {
    var itemName = $("#item-name").val().trim();
    var itemPrice = $("#item-price").val();
    if (itemName && itemPrice > 0) {
      $("#item-table tbody tr").each(function () {
        if ($(this).find("td").first().text() === itemName) {
          $(this).find("td").last().text(itemPrice);
        }
      });
    }
  });
});
input.error {
  border: 2px solid red;
}
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" id="item-name" placeholder="Enter item name" />
<input type="number" id="item-price" placeholder="Enter item price" />
<button id="add-item">Add Item</button>

<table id="item-table">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Item</th>
      <th>Price</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody></tbody>
</table>



